# Calling Naviation.PushAsync from CustomMapRenderer when clicked on a marker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am working on a xamarin project for iOS as well as Android where we are showing custom markers on the Xamarin.Forms maps, we want the user to navigate to another view when they click on a custom marker.

We are using Navigation.PushAsync to navigate through the views. this is done from the viewmodels from the non platform specific code, and navigation.PushAsync can only be used there and not from the platform specific code. Which is where the customMapRenderers are and where the onclick for the markers is handled.

So my question is how can I navigate to another view from these onClick Events?
underneath are the methods that catch the onclick.

Android:

```
private void OnMarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(MainApplication.Context, "Button Pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

iOS:

```
private void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
        {
            Title = "Event",
            Message = "Button Clicked"
        };
        alert.AddButton("Oke");
        alert.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I think theres an easier way to achieve this without custom renderer.
You can use this Library which implements much Map functionality in shared code:
https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap
But if you really need the Renderers you can Create Callback Events and react to them in your shared code.

Comment: Messenger can help too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Yuri said, you can implement this by using [Messenger](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/), here is a [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingMessagingCenter/)  about how to use `Messenger`. You can use it in `custom renderer` onClick Events, When send a `message` in `renderer`, the `Page` will received `Message`. So you can navigate to another view in your Page's `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` method.

Page:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "Navigation", async (sender) =>
{
     var page1 = new Page1();
     await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page1);
});
```

Custom Renderer:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(MainPage.getInstance(), "Navigation");
```

Comment: Thanks--this is the only way I could get a custom renderer for a label and a tap gesture simultaneously. For whatever reason, Xamarin.Forms won't let you put gestures on custom controls.