# Xamarin Forms Map pin renderer open page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, renderer

I am prety new with Renderers on Xamarin. I am following this tutorial (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/) to make a custom pin. The problem it's the following:

I need to do a custom pin, the custom pin only has 2 default labels and 1 Button. That button needs open a page from PCL project. How can I do that click button go to PCL page?

Comment: You could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406120/calling-naviation-pushasync-from-custommaprenderer-when-clicked-on-a-marker/44427338#44427338

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a message from your custom MapRenderer whenever a pin is clicked [using the Xamarin MessagingCenter](https://montemagno.com/how-to-use-xamarinforms-messaging-center/) like so:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send(YourObject, "PinClicked");
```

And then subscribe to that message somewhere in your PCL, like so:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string> (this, "PinClicked", (YourObject) => {
            // show the correct page whenever the "PinClicked" message 
            // is sent, using the details in YourObject
        });
    });
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe when you no longer wish to receive messages.

Comment: Sorry, I can not answer soon. It works like a charm, thanks!